# Conformal mapping of biaxial symmetric shapes into an (unit) circle

Tags: calculus, geometry, conformal-geometry

I would like to know if there is some kind of coordinate mapping (perhaps conformal mapping) that can map the perimeter of the circles that cross each other (like shown in the picture) into a (unit) circle? [figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1fPR.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean that you take the union of the 3 *disks* and consider the frontier ( = boundary) of this union ?

Comment: Have you heard about inversion transform, especially under its complex form $Z-z_0=\frac{k}{\overline{z-z_0}}$ form ?

Comment: Please show you have worked at least a little on this homework.

Comment: @JeanMarie yes with perimeter I meant the outer boundary of the union of the 3 disks. The reason I asked this question is that I have no clue how to start with.

Comment: What about inversion transform ? Besides, are the blue circles orthogonal to the red one ?

Comment: the blue circles don't have to be orthogonal to the red one

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there exists a *single* transformation of conformal type than can "do the job" for example as the conformal image of a square (because of the four right angles). Nevertheless, when one uses "basic" inversion

$$Z=f(z)=\frac{1}{\overline{z}}\tag{1}$$ on a square ($\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate of $z$), one gets a kind of gothic "rosace" as represented on Fig. 1,

[image]

*Fig. 1 : the image of the square (red) is the rosace (blue).*

a result which is not so far from what we want. Subsequent transformations (e.g., homographic transforms $g(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$) can *maybe* be found that give the desired result.

If we leave aside the quest for a unique transformation, I would like to show here that the inversion idea is still a good one and can bring a satisfactory answer, under the condition to use four of them.

Let us recall that, in the complex plane, the most general inversion is with center $c$ and power $p$ with the following description :

$$Z=c+\frac{p}{\overline{z-c}}\tag{2}$$

(formula (1) is the particular case of (2) when $c=0$ and $p=1$). I will assume that either you already know this transformation or you will study it separately].

The following figure :

[image]

*Fig. 2.*

is the image of the square $A(1,0),B(0,1),C(-1,0),D(0,-1)$ by specific inversions on each of its 4 sides, in such a way in particular that the overall image is connected.

- inversion with center $E$ and power $p=\frac58=0.625$ sends line segment $AB$ onto the green arc of circle,
- inversion with center $F$ and power $p=\frac52=2.5$ sends line segment $BC$ onto the blue arc of circle,
- same kind of operations for the two last ones.

There is a part of arbitrary choice for the centers as long as they are situated on the median lines of the square. Once the center is fixed, the power $p$ is more or less imposed. Moreover centers $H$ and $F$ have to be slightly changed in order that blue and magenta arcs are realy parts of a same circle.

---

**Edit** : a simpler approach :

[image]

- in quadrants 2 and 4, we keep the unit circle, whereas
- in quadrants 1 and 3, we transform by inversion the sides of the square $1,i,-1,-i$ ; we take the centers of inversion in $a+ai$ and $-(a+ai)$ resp. for $a \approx 0.29$ and power of inversion such that the different arcs are connected, which is shown possible iff $p=a^2+(a-1)^2$ :

Matlab program :

> ```
> function Z=inv(z,c,p) % inversion
>    Z=c+p/conj(z-c);
> end;
> %%% main program :
> a=0.29;c=a*(1+i);p=a^2+(a-1)^2;P=[];S=[];
> for t=-pi:0.05:pi;
>    sq=exp(i*t)/(abs(cos(t))+abs(sin(t)));
>    S=[S,sq]; % building the Square
>    if abs(cos(t-pi/4))<abs(sin(t-pi/4)); % Quadrants 2 or 4
>       b=exp(i*t);
>    else
>       b=inv(sq,sign(t)*c,p);
>    end;
>    P=[P,b]; % building the Peanut
> end;
> plot(P,'b','linewidth',5);
> plot(S,'r','linewidth',5);
> plot([c,-c],'ok')
> ```

Comment: A thought : when you mention the possibility of a conformal transform : it means that you are thinking your boundary as being the image of "something" (= a certain shape), but you should say to which kind of "something" you are thinking. My "something" is a square (rather arbitrary choice because of its 4 angles) ; but it could be something else...

Comment: See my edit....